# How can I make divs full height or height of content with Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

here is the problem

I have multiple divs that I want to be the height of the screen.

I achieved that but my problem now is that my div don't stop resizing even if my content is bigger than the div. The example speaks for itself

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.orange {
  color: #FF9800;
}

@media (max-width: 979px) {
  .custom-container {
    padding-top: 61px;
  }
}

.custom-container {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-top: 61px;
}

.inner {
  padding: 5%;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.container-fluid {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
  <a id="logo" class="nav-link col col-md-2 orange">Label</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
     <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="col col-md-8 navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#services">Services</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#photos">Photos</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container-fluid h-100">
  <div class="h-100">
    <div id="services" class="custom-container justify-content-md-center">
      <div class="inner col-md-10 orange">
        not out of bound 1
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="photos" class="h-100">
    <div class="custom-container h-100 justify-content-md-center">
      <div class="inner col-md-10 orange">
        not out of bound 2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="contact" class="h-100">
    <div class="custom-container justify-content-md-center">
      <div class="inner col-md-10">
        <div class="row orange">
         out of bound when screen size is small
        </div>
        <div> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam convallis, mi ut pretium vestibulum, mauris leo euismod mi, et laoreet erat neque quis eros. Aenean id pellentesque erat. Pellentesque tempus purus magna, id interdum tellus egestas
          a. Integer at scelerisque ipsum. Phasellus vel nibh non elit pharetra tincidunt. Nullam in pretium dui. Aliquam a consequat nulla, eu iaculis arcu. Cras posuere elit urna, sed dictum tortor laoreet ac. Donec quis massa ipsum. Fusce nec ultrices
          tortor, eu congue mauris. Suspendisse hendrerit tempor scelerisque. Aliquam at urna quis diam rhoncus feugiat a non mauris. Sed eu finibus lectus, mollis posuere lacus. Cras ullamcorper auctor hendrerit. Proin euismod metus sit amet mauris placerat
          euismod. Nullam venenatis sed mi at posuere. Phasellus felis quam, consectetur in vestibulum vel, posuere id dui. Pellentesque convallis viverra erat mattis vestibulum. Nam eros nulla, varius euismod lacus nec, vehicula dictum ipsum. Quisque
          vel justo non elit sodales pulvinar. Donec accumsan nisi efficitur augue consequat, in efficitur mauris rhoncus. Curabitur venenatis metus lacus, ac vestibulum massa euismod vel. In non erat enim. Aenean varius pellentesque tellus eu molestie.
          Sed at dolor justo. Integer interdum porttitor justo. Donec aliquet erat a consequat imperdiet. Phasellus tristique vel nunc eget consequat. Pellentesque posuere molestie placerat. Fusce egestas dignissim leo eu pellentesque. Vestibulum vehicula
          tempus lectus et lobortis.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

as you should see on small snippet's small window the text is out of bound so what I would like to achieve is a div of full height when content is smaller or equal to full height and if the content is larger than full height then my div should automatically get size of content.

Is this possible to do that? Is the overall way I'm doing this is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.orange {
  color: #FF9800;
}

@media (max-width: 979px) {
  .custom-container {
    padding-top: 61px;
  }
}

.custom-container {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-top: 61px;
}

.inner {
  padding: 5%;
  border: 1px solid white;
}


.container-fluid {
   overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
  <a id="logo" class="nav-link col col-md-2 orange">Label</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
     <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="col col-md-8 navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#services">Services</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#photos">Photos</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container-fluid">

    <div id="services" class="custom-container justify-content-md-center">
      <div class="inner col-md-10">
       <div class="row"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam convallis, mi ut pretium vestibulum, mauris leo euismod mi, et laoreet erat neque quis eros. Aenean id pellentesque erat. Pellentesque tempus purus magna, id interdum tellus egestas
          a. Integer at scelerisque ipsum. Phasellus vel nibh non elit pharetra tincidunt. Nullam in pretium dui. Aliquam a consequat nulla, eu iaculis arcu. Cras posuere elit urna, sed dictum tortor laoreet ac. Donec quis massa ipsum. Fusce nec ultrices
          tortor, eu congue mauris. Suspendisse hendrerit tempor scelerisque. Aliquam at urna quis diam rhoncus feugiat a non mauris. Sed eu finibus lectus, mollis posuere lacus. Cras ullamcorper auctor hendrerit. Proin euismod metus sit amet mauris placerat
          euismod. Nullam venenatis sed mi at posuere. Phasellus felis quam, consectetur in vestibulum vel, posuere id dui. Pellentesque convallis viverra erat mattis vestibulum. Nam eros nulla, varius euismod lacus nec, vehicula dictum ipsum. Quisque
          vel justo non elit sodales pulvinar. Donec accumsan nisi efficitur augue consequat, in efficitur mauris rhoncus. Curabitur venenatis metus lacus, ac vestibulum massa euismod vel. In non erat enim. Aenean varius pellentesque tellus eu molestie.
          Sed at dolor justo. Integer interdum porttitor justo. Donec aliquet erat a consequat imperdiet. Phasellus tristique vel nunc eget consequat. Pellentesque posuere molestie placerat. Fusce egestas dignissim leo eu pellentesque. Vestibulum vehicula
          tempus lectus et lobortis.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="photos">
    <div class="custom-container justify-content-md-center">
      <div class="inner col-md-10 orange">
        not out of bound 2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="contact">
    <div class="custom-container justify-content-md-center">
      <div class="inner col-md-10">
        <div class="row orange">
         out of bound when screen size is small
        </div>
        <div class="row"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam convallis, mi ut pretium vestibulum, mauris leo euismod mi, et laoreet erat neque quis eros. Aenean id pellentesque erat. Pellentesque tempus purus magna, id interdum tellus egestas
          a. Integer at scelerisque ipsum. Phasellus vel nibh non elit pharetra tincidunt. Nullam in pretium dui. Aliquam a consequat nulla, eu iaculis arcu. Cras posuere elit urna, sed dictum tortor laoreet ac. Donec quis massa ipsum. Fusce nec ultrices
          tortor, eu congue mauris. Suspendisse hendrerit tempor scelerisque. Aliquam at urna quis diam rhoncus feugiat a non mauris. Sed eu finibus lectus, mollis posuere lacus. Cras ullamcorper auctor hendrerit. Proin euismod metus sit amet mauris placerat
          euismod. Nullam venenatis sed mi at posuere. Phasellus felis quam, consectetur in vestibulum vel, posuere id dui. Pellentesque convallis viverra erat mattis vestibulum. Nam eros nulla, varius euismod lacus nec, vehicula dictum ipsum. Quisque
          vel justo non elit sodales pulvinar. Donec accumsan nisi efficitur augue consequat, in efficitur mauris rhoncus. Curabitur venenatis metus lacus, ac vestibulum massa euismod vel. In non erat enim. Aenean varius pellentesque tellus eu molestie.
          Sed at dolor justo. Integer interdum porttitor justo. Donec aliquet erat a consequat imperdiet. Phasellus tristique vel nunc eget consequat. Pellentesque posuere molestie placerat. Fusce egestas dignissim leo eu pellentesque. Vestibulum vehicula
          tempus lectus et lobortis.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I have changed the code, so that the div gets the height of the content, if it is larger than the screen height. Just change the height declaration of .custom-container to "auto" instead of "100%" and the min-height decaration to "100vh". You can remove the other h-100 classes in your code then.

Even though a div is a block element, its height is always the height of its content. If you want to have a full screen height (which means viewport height), you have to change 100% to 100vh (vh = viewport height).

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. obviously that work on the snippet now it's not working on my dev code let me fix that out and mark it as solved

Comment: Oh I see what you've made not exactly what I was looking for. In fact I don't want a scroll option. I would prefer the div to keep the size of the content even if it's more than screen height. Also in my dev code I have Iframes in the contact section (google form and google map).Do you know how I could o that?

Comment: ok, that was a misunderstanding then. I have changed my code to fit your needs

Comment: we're almost there but I've made a fiddle to show what problem I am facing. first div overlaps second if the content is too big https://jsfiddle.net/4yqchge7/

Comment: Removing h-100 from the content surrounding <div class="container-fluid h-100"> might help..

Comment: Also change .custom-container { min-height: 100% }  to 100vh;

Comment: yes but if I do that my second section where content is smaller than screen height don't get resized to fit screen size

Comment: check my recently added comment just below the first one :-)

Comment: Here is a new fiddle with your code up and running:
https://jsfiddle.net/SchweizerSchoggi/2t50ud39/3/

Comment: Outstanding . Thank you so much. Can you change your answer code and give more explanation.I'll mark that as answered. Great

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your desired outcome you could do:

```
.custom-container {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-top: 61px;
  /// Add Overflow control
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```